# Git messed up my files after push

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm sure this is my fault but after a push, all of the files at my destination repositories contain two copies of themselves. It looks like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

code goes here

======

same code again

/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/config.php */
>>>>>>> 6962176130afe295144f1f6a27146da27b604762
```

And this is every file on the site. Trying another push doesn't resolve the problem. I think there was a problem where all of my files had differences because my windows machine wasn't appending the new line at the end or something. How do I resolve this?

Edit: I should mention that it did this to all 1000 (or so) files. The majority of these files were not edited at all and were not part of my commit. It just did this to literally every file. I cannot think of why and all of the answers so far are just telling me to manually edit all 1000 files, which is not a reasonable solution. Doing another push didn't work either, nothing happens.

Comment: This is not a Codeigniter question...this is a git question.

Comment: Try using your editor to show whitespace on one of these files; that way you can check whether you're correct that this is a newline problem. (I think you're probably right, but it can't hurt to verify.)

Comment: Actually I just checked and the end of the page whitespace is the same on both. Now I really have no idea what's going on.

Comment: The newline problem isn't just "end of the page whitespace." It's a fundamental difference in the way each OS handles newlines: Windows uses both a carriage return and a newline character, while most other OS's just use a newline. Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems  And: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html

Comment: That's why I told you to use your editor to show whitespace.

Comment: Git does not and will not auto-merge conflicts unless you add some hooks or do some thing other than run plain git commands. It certainly would never commit auto-commit an unmerged file during a `push`. It might not have been you, or you might not have noticed. At some point you or someone working with you got conflicts (possibly due to whitespace differences) and they were committed without anyone noticing. To be clear, push commands require fast-forward merges only - a push can not itself create its own commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, `push` shouldn't actually **commit** your changes when there are merge conflicts until you've resolved them, so you should be able to undo those changes on the destination repo using `git reset --hard`.

To ensure that this doesn't happen again, take a look at this page: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of a conflicted  `merge`. Git alone couldn't merge the files, so leaved the differences in the file for you to edit. You should open your files in a editor and keep the parts you want in the

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

======
```

After the editing do the commit again.

Comment: This happened to a thousand files. I'm not sure why that git wouldn't be able to do a merge. Like I said I think the only problem was that my windows machine didn't add a newline.

Answer (score 0):

It's just showing you a conflict. The top one is your head revision and below the ===== is most likely what you pushed. I am guessing you added the commented code or there is some other minor difference. Delete one of the sets of code (The one you don't want) and you are good.

Comment: Except this happened to literally every file. The big problem is that it isn't corrected when I try to do another merge.

Comment: Are you using a mix of Linux/Windows? There has to be a difference on either side of the ======

Comment: Yes, we're using a mix of linux and windows. I think it has to do with auto adding a newline, but nothing comes up. Doing another push does nothing.

Comment: I believe you have to do some setting for Window/Linux combination but I really don't know. I am not that familiar with that side of Git as we are windows only. Have you been using git in your current setup for a while and this is the first time this has happened?

Comment: No, this happened on the first push from my windows box.

Comment: See the answer above as I think it solves your issue in the link: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings  There are some precautions you have to take when mixing OS. I also believe you must be careful with case-sensitivity but I may be mistaken.

Comment: "Somebody" did a `git commit -a` or a `git add .` or similar, and didn't care about the conflicts...